# Is RPC Miner still the preferred BTC mining software for a Mac?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, mac

I'd like to get a sense of how impossible it is to mine BTC as part of a pool on a MacBook Pro.  I figured there was some mining software out there but Uncle Google only showed some stuff from 2013.  I eventually clicked around to something called "RPC Miner", which led to this link (http://uploaded.net/file/49dw65r3), which I sure hope isn't a virus.  Is RPC Miner still the preferred mining software of choice for Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Mining bitcoin with a CPU/GPU is now basically impossible, the network is secured by ASIC machines that are *many orders of magnitude* more efficient than a CPU/GPU miner could be. You could plug your Macbook pro into a mining pool, but you will literally just waste money on electricity, and get zero payout in return.

Not only that, Macbook Pros (or any other laptop for that matter) are not build to be run as hard as mining requires. You run a serious risk of damaging your computer, with basically no chance of reaping a reward.

You will literally have better odds buying a lottery ticket with the money you would spend on electricity.

Comment: Thahks but you didn't answer my question.  If I were to purchase the lottery ticket, would it be using a service like RPC Miner? Or is there another client for the Mac?

Comment: I meant a literal lottery ticket, unrelated to cryptocurrency. There are probably no up-to-date mining clients built specifically for macbook pros, as using one to mine would be an outright waste of electricity.

Answer (score 1):

He didn't answer your question,  but he gave you more useful information.

I mine with Mac.  I use the Mac Pro (3,1 4,1 5,1).

Even with these machines which are orders of magnitude faster than your laptop, I don't use the cpus.  I use USB based ASICs (antminer) or GPU's (Nvidia 1060, etc.)

I like the Macminer software which is basically a GUI wrapper for the standard mining tools (CGminer, BFGminer).

Basically, I don't see much return this way either these days.  The MacPros in question are servers that are running anyhow,  and are in a cool ventilated location.  I have not tried RPC-miner on the Mac yet.